# Swift error after declaring a background using SpriteKit on Playgrounds

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift-playground

I'm relatively new to learning the Swift language so I don't know what I'm missing, but I can't seem to see why this would not be working. My goal is to add a background to my scene using SpriteKit, but whenever I try to add one, playgrounds takes a second and then displays an error that says:

> There was a problem running this playground.

I already have a scene set up using SpriteKit so when this piece of code is not present I do get a black screen, but for some reason everything seems to fail when this segment is in:

```
        let bg = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "IMG_0483.jpg")))
        bg.setScale(2.0)
        bg.zPosition = -10
        bg.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)
        addChild(bg)
```

Here is the larger context of the script:

```
import SpriteKit

public class GameScene: SKScene {
    var player: SKSpriteNode!
    
    public override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        
        // Backround
        let bg = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "IMG_0483.jpg")))
        bg.setScale(2.0)
        bg.zPosition = -10
        bg.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)
        addChild(bg)
    }
}
```

and here is my main where I'm calling it

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let skView = SKView(frame: .zero)

let gameScene = GameScene(size: UIScreen.main.bounds.size)

gameScene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
skView.presentScene(gameScene)


PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = skView
PlaygroundPage.current.wantsFullScreenLiveView = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
      let bg = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "image.jpg")
       bg.setScale(2.0)
       bg.zPosition = -10
       bg.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)
       addChild(bg)
```

Where you display the scene:

```
    let skView = SKView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let gameScene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")
    gameScene?.scaleMode = .aspectFill
    skView.presentScene(gameScene)
    PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = skView
```